# I have tried the general methods of ODE solving and Laplace transform and yet can't seem to get an answer!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hum8f.png)

So, I tried solving this question (in the above link) and I ended up with a differential equation which i could not solve with laplace tranforms or by any other means known to me, I need help to solve the differential equation which now looks like this:

mx"= eE + (e/c)Hy'

my"= -(e/c)Hx'

where e=electric charge
      c=speed of light
      E=electric field
       H=magnetic field

and they are basically constants .

As I have said, I went through the general methods of ODE solving as well as Laplace transforms but none were able to give me the correct answer.

Comment: Should be $-eE$ in the first equation. Laplace transform will do the job so the next question is, where did you get a problem using that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate $\quad my''=-\frac{e}{c}Hx'$
$$my'=-\frac{e}{c}Hx +0$$
The integration constant is $0$ because zero initial velocity and displacement.
$$mx''=eE+\frac{e}{c}Hy'=eE+\frac{e}{c}H(-\frac{e}{m\:c}Hx)$$
$$x''+\left(\frac{e}{m\:c}H\right)^2 x=\frac{eE}{m}$$
Let $\omega=\frac{e}{m\:c}H$
$$x''+\omega^2x=\frac{e}{m\:c}H$$
I suppose that you can solve it for $x(t)$ and then compute $y(t)$. This will give you the expected result.